# How to update a column on change of a specific column in the same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Two of the columns in a table are `Province` and `Province_image`. `Province_image` column is of type `Blob` used to hold a [URL Image](https://cvfc2020.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ON.jpg) where `ON` is the name of the province.

When a user changes `Province`, I want to trigger an update to `Province_image` also - something like

```
Set Province_image = concat('https://cvfc2020.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/',Province,'.jpg')
```

Creating the update string for `Province_Image` is not the problem. How to trigger the update is stumping me.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you really want to do this in the database - triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: i am using MySQL 5.6